# where does DataFrameWriter.bucketBy() stores the data?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use the DataFrameWriter.bucketBy() method to bucket the output by given columns. But where exactly the output data will be stored?

is it stored in Memory or is it possible to store it in file system?

**Code:**

```
>>> (df.write.format('parquet')  
...     .bucketBy(100, 'year', 'month')
...     .mode("overwrite")
...     .saveAsTable('bucketed_table'))
```

Answer (score 0):

saveAsTable will always store the dataframe into HDFS as Table.

Comment: how to give the hdfs path? is it through options?

Comment: saveAsTable stores at /user/hive/warehouse by default which is an HDFS path.